# prevent a node from removing from the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, mutation-observers

I want to **prevent an element from being removed** by using something like preventDefault().
Ex.

```
myNode.on("remove", (e) => {
       e.preventDefault();
    });
```

I can detect the removal by using MutationObserver but I can't prevent the element from removing.
Appreciate your help.

Comment: Ultimately you cant. Even if you made a function to prevent it, I could just remove that one first.

Comment: You can't. If this is for some security measure as part of a form, you would need to validate the data sent on the server side to ensure it meets business logic requirements.

Comment: may be... clone the dom and back ...

Answer (score 4):

You can't. There's no event fired (other than the deprecated mutation events, and they [weren't cancellable](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMNodeRemoved)), mutation observers can't prevent it from happening, etc.

You can detect it happened and put it back, but you can't prevent that specific one from being removed.

Here's a minimal example of doing that; in this case, the code assumes it should be at the top of its parent, but of course that's not true all the time. If you have to insert it somewhere special, you'll need to know where it goes before it's removed.

```js
const observer = new MutationObserver(records => {
    for (const {target, removedNodes} of records) {
        const element = Array.prototype.find.call(removedNodes, ({id}) => id === "the-element");
        if (element) {
            console.log("Re-inserted at top of parent");
            target.insertBefore(element, target.firstChild);
        }
    }
});
observer.observe(document.body, {
    subtree: true,
    childList: true
});
document.getElementById("the-btn").addEventListener("click", () => {
    document.getElementById("the-element").remove();
});
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="the-element">this is the element</div>
  <input id="the-btn" type="button" value="Remove It">
</div>
```

Comment: I had tried to do such a thing by cloning the removing element and re-adding it but it doesn't work(the elements are disordered and screen refreshes on click event) let clone = $(".stocks div").first() clone.insertBefore(".stocks div:first")

Comment: Thanks for this! Saved me some experimentation T.J!

Answer (score 0):

Note that Object.freeze/Object.seal will NOT prevent node removal. That's not explicitly mentioned in Mozilla's knowledge base:

```
arguments[1] = HTMLDocument.prototype.createElement.call(document, "style")

Node.prototype.appendChild.call(document.head, arguments[1])

Object.freeze(arguments[1])

HTMLElement.prototype.remove.call(arguments[1]) // gone
```

Is a problem if you insert css into the DOM on the fly on pages you visit to modify the way they look, but some pages are messing with the styles on "DOMContentLoaded" and will remove your styles. With javascript it's not a problem, because you can simply eval it or "importScripts" to web workers, no need to add anything to the DOM, but with css it's a problem. So you have to take care of your css styles or any other nodes you add by using a MutationObserver. Give your node an explicit className and monitor for changes inside the MutationObserver callback. Example:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(arguments[0], function()
{
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(arguments[0].addedNodes[0]) == "[object HTMLHeadElement]" || (Object.prototype.toString.call(arguments[0].removedNodes[0]) == "[object HTMLStyleElement]" && arguments[0].removedNodes[0].className == "myFancyStyle") || (Object.prototype.toString.call(arguments[0].target) == "[object HTMLStyleElement]" && arguments[0].target.className == "myFancyStyle"))
    {
        /*
            if document.head has just been added to the dom, attach your style to it

            if your style has been removed (arguments[0].removedNodes[0]), re-add it

            if your style has been messed with (arguments[0].target), remove the style first, who knows what the website did to it, then re-add it

            If you are re-adding it, better set a setTimeout of 0 to wait for a frame, because if the website script is looping thru a NodeList and you insert another node during their loop, you'll break their iteration !
        */
    }
})
```